# How do I run python code on each task in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a sequence of Tasks on my DAG

eg.

```
task1 >> task2 >> task3
```

What I need is to put across the tasks functionality without repeating code.
For example logging, would like to execute log.info(task_id) per task
Or some external operation, like http call per task

I am new to airflow and probably missing all the concepts, but how I would do something like this?
a custom operator?
An interceptor for each task execution.

I would like to avoid something like this

```
[task1,logging] >> [task2,logging] >> [task3, logging]
```

Another example
If I try to process the xcom params stored per task with a common way how would I do it? Instead of putting the process logic on every task I would like to have the xcom per task on this seperate operator/task/whatever will be to process, same goes for logging or other functionalities

Triggering my operator/task/whatever per task i guess would be one way to do this, but again do I need to add it every time like this on each task?

```
[task1,process_xcom] >> [task2,process_xcom] >> [task3, process_xcom]
```

> A similar concept in java could be the usage of Aspects on Services

Comment: Are you looking to pass the logger between tasks?

Comment: not exactly I would prefer to have it on a separate task or something, a common place to execute for each task

Comment: I am not sure want you exactly need, but if you want to do something on every task execute you can add to the default_args of the dag a parameter to call it. if that what you. mean I'll write full answer with example

Comment: @ozs edited my question with an example at the end hope this helps to grasp what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Few option that I think can help in this case :

1. you can set in the dag default_args "on_execute_callback" that each task before it starts will call this function or "on_success_callback"/"on_failure_callback" when it ends.

the advantage here is that all tasks will call this function and you need to defined it once per dag.

```
    def log(context):
        print(context["ti"].task_id)

    with DAG(
       dag_id="test_dag",
       schedule_interval=None,
       default_args={
          "start_date": datetime(2022, 1, 1),
          "on_execute_callback": log,
          "catchup": False,
    },
  ) as dag:
```

2.another way is, on each task you can call pre_execute and/or post_execute, for example if you want to do something with the xcom.

in this example I push all json keys to xcom as separate key

```
def push_json_xcom(context, result):
    ti = context["ti"]
    data = result if isinstance(result, dict) else json.loads(result)
    for key, value in data.items():
        ti.xcom_push(key, value)

PythonOperator(task_id="test_id", post_execute=push_json_xcom, python_callable=python_func)
```

Comment: do you think that creating an abstract operator with all the functionality I want to add to each task and the extending for each task operator would be reasonable? should I also try this? Also on your answer the second option looks better to me

Comment: @PanosK the idea of creating an abstract class will cause you to create other classes for each existing operators every unique operator you use, for example if you use PythonOperator and BashOperator then you will need to extend both and so on. it is a possibility that will work and its up to you according the dag implementation and kind of operators you use